# What is the mean free path (MFP) of a Cosmic microwave background radiation (CMBR) photon?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background, mean-free-path

If the IGM (inter-galactic medium) had a massive particle (proton) every cubic metre, or a carbon grain every cubic kilometre, what would be the MFP of a CMBR photon? The coherence length of the photon would be expected to be in the order millimetres. The time evolution of the wave front, in the plane at right angles to the direction of propagation would grow to the order of light years on its journey to our present observations. Considering the carbon particles alone would collapse the wave function within a few kilometres, a new wave function of slightly lower energy could be created along with two very much lower energy photons, one associated with the heat generated in the carbon particle, and the other associated with the momentum gained by the particle. This process of annihilation and creation would continue all the way to our observations. This is a reasonable attempt at a qualitative interpretation. This attempt is also consistent with several modern theories and observations of the affect of dust in the IGM.

[Universe opacity and EBL](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01753)

[Calculating the redshifts of distant galaxies from first principles by the new tired light theory (NTL)](https://doi.org/10.1088/1742-6596/1251/1/012007)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_%28cosmology%29): “Shortly after recombination, the photon mean free path became larger than the Hubble length.”

Comment: @ G. Smith...What about re-ionization? How does that effect the MFP?  Even carbon dust grains are ionized, how does that effect the interaction cross section  of  carbon dust and the subsequent interaction with CMBR photons?

Comment: Read the second paragraph [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reionization#Background). It doesn’t give the MFP but it says that the universe remained transparent after re-ionization, implying a huge MFP. For more detail, I think you would need to consult a graduate-level cosmology textbook since no experts have answered.

Comment: @G. Smith....This is an active area of research and as such textbooks may not help, this link may indicate the current level of research in this area.               https://jumpshare.com/v/lCw7nbSN6P79vNU2zObh

Comment: OK. This site may not a good place to get answers about current research. Unfortunately, we don’t have experts in every physics subfield who are up-to-date on the latest research. If we had an expert on the latest thinking about the MFP of the CMB, they probably would have provided an answer.

Comment: However, it is also possible that any such expert decided not to engage with you after reading some of your intemperate language, such as calling us a “nest of bigots”.

Comment: @G. Smith...I consider myself as an expert in EM application and theory. I found it unpleasant  being insulted by comments like "poor quality" posts. I believe that theoretical physicists and mathematicians look down on Maxwell's Quaint EM adherents, as "dinosaurs".  When I look at the profiles of those that attack me, I notice a definite economy of EM experts. My posts on electrical engineering are appreciated, I assume that  the experts are operating there, rather than here, at "physics" I rather think that I have been on the receiving end of intemperate language?

Comment: There is no requirement that any member of PSE be an expert on anything. If your assumption is that everyone who responds to one of your posts is, or should be, an expert, then PSE is not for you. All members are free to judge the quality of others’ posts, regardless of their own expertise. (Yes, this is sometimes exasperating!)  *No one* is allowed to call anyone a bigot. You *badly* misunderstand the way that PSE operates.

Comment: From what you have written in various questions, it seems apparent that you are highly competent on classical electromagnetism but not knowledgeable about, and in fact skeptical of, quantum electrodynamics. To someone like me who studied both, QED skeptics are far out on the fringiest fringe of physics.

Comment: 99.9% or so of physicists accept QED as the most accurate physical theory ever developed, because *that’s what experiments show*. If you reject QED, and believe that the electromagnetic field does not need to be quantized, then you cannot expect to be taken seriously by the experts who are here.

Comment: This could turn into a very long back-and-forth, which is prohibited in comments, so I will probably not respond further. If I have misunderstood your position on quantizing the EM field then I apologize in advance.

Comment: The Muon anomaly is not supporting QED very well. Give me one example in support of QED claim as "the most accurate physical theory ever developed"?

Comment: QED’s prediction of the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron is confirmed by experiment to *ten significant digits*. The muon anomaly has not caused mainstream physicists to be skeptical of QED in the slightest. If true, it is assumed to indicate new non-EM interactions.

Comment: It seems clear that you *are* a QED skeptic, as I previously perceived. You are entitled to your opinion, but you cannot claim that it is a mainstream one.

Comment: Max Planck, one of the so called founding fathers of QM did not believe in "photons". His quantization was originally only proposed to exist at the point of emission and detection and behave as per Maxwell in the radiating field.

Comment: QED did not predict the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron to "ten significant digits". The measurements came first and QED followed, several measurements over many years of ever increasing precision always preceded QED.  Similarly the Lamb shift measurement preceded QED. I have studied QM for 40 years and have become ever more skeptical.  QED fails to predict anomalous g factors for high Z particles, it seems to be "tuned" to the electron?

Comment: @G. Smith...QED seems off topic and not related to my original question regarding the MFP of the CMBR photon? Should I offer a bounty or answer my own question?

Answer (score -1):

The mean free path of a CMB Wave function (assuming Copenhagen interpretation) would be  no more than a few metres on average over  the 13.5 billion years of travel, if we assumed an ion or dust mote every metre or so. The wave function would collapse and a new slightly lower energy photon would be created because the ion or dust would gain some tiny amount of momentum from the collapsed wavefunction. this means after 13.5 billion years the CMB bears no relationship to the original source. The blackbody (BB) spectrum would develop over time as the many ion's and dust constantly exchange energy between one another over time, this is the mechanism non Doppler redshift and BB radiaton in this case, the BB component is just as in the old carbon cavity experiments. In summary the CMB is not a clear window into the past!

Comment: How would you explain the persistence of the structure (anisotropies) in the observed CMB signal?

Comment: Also, wouldn’t one sub micron sized particle per cubic meter be associated with a mean free path of order 10^3km for microwave photons? (And if the particles are roughly micron sized, wouldn’t they have a somewhat noticeable gravitational effect?)